# Excel 2013 After Insert Data in 1 column another column from same sheet needs updated using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013 and have two sheets.

"Sheet 1" has the following

```
Product      Com 1    Com 2   Com 3
Radio Head          
Tr          
Rx
```

"Sheet 2" has the following

```
Prod        Com 1   Com 2   Com 3
Radio Head  
Tr
Rx
```

Now to my problem:

Whenever I type a value in Com1 from Sheet1, I want value '1' in Com1 for the Sheet2 for the respective field.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post with your efforts to reach your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `VBA` to achieve what you need. Formula to set 1 if not empty and 0 if empty. I have used first cell from the `Sheet1`.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1),0,1)
```